# How can I set an id to id h:commandLink from a c:forEach in order to be accesed by JS?

Tags: javascript, jsf, foreach, commandlink, trinidad

In a project with JSF 1.1 with Apache Trinidad, I need to create several dynamic h:commandLink, and they need to be accessed by JS in order to be clicked on loading.

What I have is this for js:

```
    var cardsSize = window.document.getElementById("miForm:cardsSize").value;
    for(var i = 0; i <= cardsSize; i++){    
        setTimeout(function(){
            var buttonCard = window.document.getElementById("miForm:buttonCard_"+i);
            buttonCard.click();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

And what I have in .jsp is:

```
<c:forEach var = "i" begin="0" varStatus="index" end="#{pageFlowScope.cardsSize}">
    <h:commandLink id="buttonCard_#{index.index}"
        style="display:none" 
        action="#{confirmBacking.generateDocument}"
        onclick="document.forms['miForm'].target='_blank';">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{confirmBacking.indexCard}" value="#{index}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that when I create the commandLink with c:forEach, using a dynamic id ends in **According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute "[id]" does not accept any expressions**

Other solutions for c:forEach or ui:repeat to create several commandLink with different params implies not to have and id, but I need ids since JS does not have other way to access these objects as far as I know.

Comment: if you use a ui:repeat, you'll automatically get an id with an index postfixed to it...

Comment: how can I know that id in order to access to it from javascript?

Comment: Think of it all being html... How can you read the attribute of an html element in javascript? Very generic and 'googleable' question

Comment: may you please post an example using ui:repeat and setting this id with the postfixed value?

Comment: Anyway, ui:repeat is not an option for me since the project stack have JSP, not Facelets, but i'm still interested in seeing a solution with ui:repeat

Comment: Then next time state so a little earlier... it is an important part of problems (using an old combination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css class selector instead:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="buttonCard_#{index.index}"
```

and get each button by:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("buttonCard_"+i)
```

Comment: Perhaps this was not useful for me, since "end" tag of c:forEach neither accept EL expression, it was a valid solution.